# Linear quantile regression v.s. two-step OLS regression

Tags: statistics, regression, quantile

Assume we have a linear model $y = 10 + 0.5x + \epsilon$ where the $\epsilon$ is a random noise. We have $n$ samples $(y_1, x_1),\cdots,(y_n, x_n)$ and want to calculate the 90th percentile y conditional on x based on these n observations. Consider the following two approaches:

1. Use the classic linear quantile regression. It will return a 90th percentile function $y = a_1 + a_2x$.
2. Use the OLS regression to estimate the interception and the coefficient of x first, which we assume to be $y = b_1 + b_2x$. Then calculate the estimated residuals $\hat{\epsilon}_i = y_i - b_1 - b_2 x_i$. We find the 90th percentile of $\hat{\epsilon}_i$ through sorting and denote it as $c_1$. The 90th percentile function is then $y = b_1 + b_2x + c_1$.

My question is: will the two approaches return the same results? (I think they are the same when n tends to infinity.) If so, why should we still use Approach 1 instead of Approach 2, which seems faster and has good theoretical guarantees as well?

Comment: Empirically the two approaches appear to give different estimates of the slope (the quantile regression slope tends to be slightly higher than the shifted OLS regression slope) though the difference seems to reduce towards $0$ as $n$ increases